# How to control sibling's width in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two `<p>` elements under an `<h1>` element and I want the width of the rendered paragraphs never to exceed 90% width of the content in the header. The contents of the `<p>` and `<h1>` elements are generated dynamically on the server side with Django and may also wrap on smaller screen sizes.

I've tried `d-flex`, `flex-column`, `flex-shrink` with marginal luck. The best I was able to do is dynamic and responsive resizing of the `<p>`s, but I lost the ability to center the 3 elements horizontally in the parent container div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">A Short Big Title!</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is a pretty long sentence, and it could be longer than the title above, however, I would not like its width to exceed 90% of that h1 tag above.</p>
    <p><i>This is a shorter sentence, however, I still have the same hopes for its width.</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "never exceed 90% width of the h1" - you mean the width of the h1 element, which is set to 100%, or really the content of the h1 element?

Comment: You're right, I mean the content. Will update question

Answer (score 0):

**Strategy-1 (blue)**: To get 90% of the paragraphs under the heading, we first checked the width of the heading... which is 100 of the viewport's width; which means that to get 90% width, we'd have to put a margin of 5% (of the viewport's width) on the left/right;

**Strategy-2 (green)**: we checked the rendered width of the `<h1>`, which was 413px, next we got our paragraph to be 413px, we put the margins on auto to get nice centralized text;

both solutions implemented in the **snippet** below:

```css
.divStrategy1 p {
  margin: 0 5vw;
  color: blue;
}

.divStrategy2 p {
  width: 413px;
  margin: auto;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="text-center divStrategy1">
  <h1 class="display-4">A Short Big Title!</h1>

  <p class="lead">This is a pretty long sentence, and it could be longer than the title above, however, I would not like its width to exceed 90% of that h1 tag above.</p>

  <p><i>This is a shorter sentence, however, I still have the same hopes for its width.</i></p>
</div>

<div class="text-center divStrategy2">
  <h1 class="display-4">A Short Big Title!</h1>

  <p class="lead">This is a pretty long sentence, and it could be longer than the title above, however, I would not like its width to exceed 90% of that h1 tag above.</p>

  <p><i>This is a shorter sentence, however, I still have the same hopes for its width.</i></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue with these solutions is that the h1 element may wrap on different screen sizes or have different dynamically generated server side content. So, at the time of writing CSS, the width of the h1 is not known.

Comment: @Corey, interesting intent... I am not sure that what you're trying to achieve is possible... you should update the question with this information that you've put in the comments... what someone would normally do is to put a div with an arbitrary width, then all your content will remain inside the width for that div